# Accessing Apache over LAN

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

I am running a headless install of Centos, which I would like to use as a web server. I have installed Apache, and successfully tested http://localhost using the Links browser via SSH.

I would like to be able to access it from my laptop (MacBook Pro), but when I type in 192.168.0.6(the Centos LAN IP) in my web-browser it does not load.

Listening is set to 80 in the httpd.conf file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but on every system I've used (even my phone), you can do it more or less that way if both systems are on the same subnet of the same lan.  You might need to use the form `http://192.168.0.6`. This is the default behavior with a new install of Apache2.

Comment: Hmm so it doesn't look like i'm doing anything wrong per se. I wonder if it could be something to do with the network setup on the CentOS device?

Comment: I have checked and port 80 is definitely open.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this with the following command:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-service=http
```